# How to install a previous exact version of a NPM package?

Tags: node.js, npm

I used nvm to download node v0.4.10 and installed npm to work with that version of node.

I am trying to install express using

```
npm install express -g
```

and I get an error that express requires node version >= 0.5.0.

Well, this is odd, since I am following the directions for a node+express+mongodb tutorial [here](http://howtonode.org/e84d3e8548d86d90eb82878e4d71dc21f4d63b93/express-mongodb) that used node v0.4.10, so I am assuming express is/was available to node v0.4.10. If my assumption is correct, how do I tell npm to fetch a version that would work with my setup?

Comment: Why don't you just update your Node version? Pretty sure there should be many more good additions than broken behavior that you will find.

Comment: Sometimes that's not an option. If he used nvm to downgrade, there might be a reason, such as some other group controls the executable node version he has to use.

Answer (score 1999, accepted):

If you have to install an older version of a package, just specify it

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

For example: `npm install express@3.0.0`

You can also add the `--save` flag to that command to add it to your package.json dependencies, or `--save --save-exact` flags if you want that exact version specified in your package.json dependencies.

The `install` command is documented here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

If you're not sure what versions of a package are available, you can use:

```
npm view <package> versions
```

And `npm view` can be used for viewing other things about a package too. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view

Comment: I believe this will install the nearest major version that matches, so it might not be what you expect http://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/1074400

Comment: @AakilFernandes if you specify an exact version, an exact version will be installed. If you specify a semantic version range, then you might get a non-exact match. There's nothing unique about the install command in that respect.

Comment: Also worth noting that when you run 'npm install express' you are actually running 'npm install express@latest'

Comment: `npm view <package> versions -json` to see every single version, avoiding the ellipsis at the end of a list with many versions.

Comment: If you use `npm install express@3.0.0`, you won't get the exact version 3.0.0, you'll get the latest 3.x.x version. To get the specific version, you have to use `npm install express@3.0.0 --save-exact`. See this blog post: https://60devs.com/npm-install-specific-version.html

Comment: @PatrickHund no, `npm install express@3.0.0` will get you _exactly_ version 3.0.0. `npm install express@^3.0.0` would get you the latest 3.x.x. `--save-exact` affects how it's written to packages.json, which I already covered in my answer. Also note, `--save-exact` has to be used in combination with either `--save` or `--save-dev` - it's not enough to use it on its own.

Comment: i can confirm that you will NOT get exact version with ^1.2.3, our build pipeline then tried to pull in 1.2.10 (latest sub version) and the build failed.  'npm i 1.2.3' puts the '^' which will not guarantee an exact match when the project builds especially in another location.

Answer (score 136):

It's quite easy. Just write this, for example:

```
npm install -g npm@4.6.1
```

Or:

```
npm install -g npm@latest    // For the last stable version
npm install -g npm@next      // For the most recent release
```

Comment: Thanks for the `latest` and `next` version tags!

Comment: @inaps you *might* add a note that the `-g` flag is specifically for packages you want installed globally as a lot of users will get to this page and merely copy/paste without realizing how they are about to impact their package ecosystem. We've all been "that guy"

Comment: this will install the exact version locally but will put '^4.6.1' in package.json which means other developers or build tools may get another subversion which may not be what you want and cause a build to fail.

Answer (score 113):

First remove old version, then run **literally** the following:

```
npm install express@3.X
```

or

```
npm install express@4.X
```

and for stable or recent

```
npm install -g npm@latest    // For the last stable version
npm install -g npm@next      // For the most recent release
```

Comment: Is that a literal `X` or a stand-in for some numeric version number?

Comment: That was an either/or question, not a yes/no question. I tried `npm install express@3.X`, and it seemed to work. Is that a feature or an accident of the way `npm` parses the version number?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, it is! Hehe, just kidding... It's the way `npm` parses it, see: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#x-ranges-12x-1x-12-

Comment: @gonz: So it's a literal `X`.

Comment: I just wanted to address why did that work for you. I don't know Saurabh's original intention or what you are trying to do. 3.X would mean >= 3.0 and < 4.0.

Comment: This answer needs to be edited to explain the `.X`.

Answer (score 46):

In my opinion that is easiest and fastest way:

`$ npm -v`

4.2.0

`$ npm install -g npm@latest-3`

...

`$ npm -v`

3.10.10

Answer (score 11):

you can update your npm package by using this command:

`npm install <package_name>@<version_number>`

example:
`npm install yargs@12.0.2`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following command to install a previous version of an npm package:

```
npm install packagename@version
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a general way to solve this type of problems, which could be helpful too,  especially when cloning repositories to run them locally, but requires a little more analysis of the versions.

With the package `npm-check-updates` I verify the versions of the packages (according to the package.json file) that are not declared in their latest available versions, as shown in the figure (https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates):

[image]

With this information we can verify the update status of the different packages and make decisions as to which packages to upgrade / degrade and which ones do not.

Assuming that we decided to update all the packages as they are listed, we can use the `ncu -u` command which only modifies your package.json file. Run `npm install` to update your installed packages and package-lock.json.

Then, depending on the requirements of the repository, we can refine what is needed, installing the specific versions with
 `npm view <package> versions` and  `npm install <package>@<version>`

Answer (score 1):

If you have to install an older version of a package, just specify it

npm install @
For example: npm install express@3.0.0

You can also add the --save flag to that command to add it to your package.json dependencies, or --save --save-exact flags if you want that exact version specified in your package.json dependencies.

The install command is documented here: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

If you're not sure what versions of a package are available, you can use:

npm view  versions
And npm view can be used for viewing other things about a package too. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I found: add package name with the version in `package.json` and then run `npm install`

```
"next-seo": "^5.4.0",
"next-themes": "^0.1.1",
"nextjs-progressbar": "^0.0.14",
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `npm config set save-exact=true` if you want to install the exact version