# c9.io - npm installs outdated packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a workspace on c9.io, and I am using node.js. I am trying to update socket.io from 0.9.17 to the latest version. However, whenever I run the command `npm update socket.io` it installs the same version. How can I fix this?

Comment: Remove socket.io

Then try:

`npm install socket.io@<version you want>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the latest available package:

```
npm install <package>
```

To install a version directly (**no** need to uninstall first):

```
npm install <package>@<version>
```

If you're not sure what versions of a package are available, you can use:

```
npm view <package> versions
```

Don't forget the `--save` flag to add dependencies to your `package.json` file.

Source: [How do I install a previous version of an npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15892076/1218980)

## About npm update

> However, if app's `package.json` contains:
>
> ```
> "dependencies": {   
>    "dep1": "~1.1.1" 
> }
> ```
>
> In this case, running `npm update` will install `dep1@1.1.2`. Even though the latest tag points to **1.2.2**, this version does not satisfy **~1.1.1**, which is equivalent to **>=1.1.1 <1.2.0**. So the highest-sorting version that satisfies **~1.1.1** is used, which is **1.1.2**.

Source: [npm update - Tilde Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update#tilde-dependencies)