# Install 2 versions of ionic 2 on the same computer

Tags: installation, ionic2

I have ionic2 rc1 on my MacBook now, but my client wants rc0. How can I install and manage 2 versions of ionic at the same MacBook?

Comment: If you want to `npm install` a specific version, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/15890958/3001761

Comment: so in my case is it `npm install ionic@2.0rc0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to update the package.json with the Ionic version you need, in your case:

```
ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.0"
```

The npm install is for the global Ionic CLI and App/Scripts

Comment: Just for clarification, each project has its own package.json, you can have the latest Ionic2 Cli installed globally and still use whichever versión your client wants.