# Extract attachment from MIME email using Node.js 4.3

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-web-services, email-attachments, email-parsing

The NPM module "mailparser" (by Andris Reinman in Estonia) would be perfect for this. However, mailparser wants Node version 6.0 but I can only use Node version 4.3. This is because the e-mail parsing must execute within Amazon Web Services (AWS). Node version 4.3 is the only version AWS supports currently.

Comment: Try to upgrade your node.js version: http://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version or install an older mailparser: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-an-npm-package

Comment: The solution that worked for me is "simple-mailparser-javascript" by Florian Narr of Austria. Jed Sundwall of AWS pointed me to it here:  
https://github.com/floscom/simple-mailparser-javascript/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

It looks like AWS supports node 6.1 now