# Using a version of react compatible with react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

React-select uses the React.create Class. After I did npm install it seems something happened that I can not use React-Select anymore. I suspect it is because of a newer version of react that has been just installed.
How can I do to install the latest compatible version of react-select? Is there a solution to this problem?

Thx

Comment: Try raising an issue at [their github repo](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)

Comment: I will, but is there a way to install a specific version of react?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-an-npm-package