# How to degrade angular cli version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am working with angular 4 and I am using **angular-cli** version 1.6.4.
But currently, i am getting [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9185) issue while building my project.

I came to know that i can fix issue by degrading version to **angular-cli-1.6.3**

Can anyone suggest me to downgrade the same?

I tried to install package using npm command, but its not worked.

As per angular cli git hub discussion i came to know that package degrade may work.but i am not getting any 1.6 version rather than 1.6.4 by using npm install.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a previous version of an npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-an-npm-package)

Comment: I tried it as normal npm degrade.but its not succeded.

Comment: As per angular cli git hub discussion i came to know that package degrade may work.but i am not getting any 1.6 version rather than 1.6.4 by using npm instal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have the same issue i what i do was:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1.6.3 --save
```

also you can change the file package.json in the line where its the version from "@angular/cli": "1.6.4", to "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",

and run again `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Run `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.3`

Comment: As per angular cli git hub discussion i came to know that package degrade may work.but i am not getting any 1.6 version  rather than 1.6.4 by using npm install

Answer (score 0):

Angular allows for you to install an older version of the package. Traditionally, the command is setup as follows

```
npm install -g <package>@<version>
```

For example: `npm install @angular/cli@1.6.3`

Adding the `--save` flag to your command, adds it to your

> package.json

If you like, you can also use `--save --save-exact` flags if you want that exact version specified in your package.json.

While on this, here are a useful resource

If you're not sure what versions of a package are available, you can use:

```
npm view <package> versions
```

used to check which versions of the particular package are available, for example

```
npm view @angular/cli versions
```

can be used to check, which versions of angular/cli are available.

If you'd like some more detail about what you can do with the `npm install` command, check the link [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)