# How to install specific version of bootstrap using Angular CLI

Tags: npm

I am trying to include bootstrap 3.7 in my angular 2 project by using
CLI command -

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

I have requirement to use bootstrap 3.7 version. But, it is installing the latest version of bootstrap i..e bootstrap 4.

How to install specific version of bootstrap using CLI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a previous version of an npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-an-npm-package)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

From the official bootstrap documentation :

> You can also install Bootstrap using npm:

`npm install bootstrap@3 --save`

Comment: For specific version -  npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save

Answer (score 13):

This is related to NPM, not angular. There are 2 ways:

1. npm install bootstrap@version --save(replace version with the desired version).
   *Using --save is a best pratice. It adds the bootstrap dependencies to package.json*
2. Check your package.json and update `"bootstrap": "4.0.0"` to `3.3.7`

Answer (score 7):

You Can install Bootstrap Version 3.3.7 using below comment.

> $ npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save

Answer (score 3):

Specify the version you want in the 'dependencies' section of your package.json, then from your root project folder in the console run this:

**npm install**

Comment: I have noticed that everyone uses 'npm install bootstrap'. why not 'npm install --save bootstrap'? Will it not throw an error when the codebase is shared with some other developer as it will not be added in package.json but is being referencecd in angular.json file.

PS. I am new to angular 7. Just curious to know why people dont use --save for this package

Answer (score 3):

Use following command:

```
npm install bootstrap@version --save
```

Replace the **version** with the respective version you need. See the example below to install **v.3.3.7**

```
npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install bootstrap using npm command.

```
npm install bootstrap@version --save
```

Here "@version" is the version of bootstrap. You can replace it by specific version as below.

```
npm install bootstrap@3.7 --save
```

You can also use @latest to install latest version of it.

Answer (score 2):

Install Bootstrap Specific Version in Angular

```
npm install bootstrap@4.6 --save // 4.6 is a version value you can change it accordingly.
```

If you like to install bootstrap along with JQuery in Angular

```
npm install bootstrap@@4.6 jquery --save
```

Note: you can try without --save also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the Bootstarp without jQuery library (which is recommended), there is a package named `ng-bootstrap`.
You can install it by running this script:

`npm install ng-bootstrap@latest`

Also, it is recommended to install packages using Angular CLI.

You may ask why?
Because it can update your project with configuration changes, for example if it needs to update your `angular.json`, to place `css` or `script` file addresses.
For more info regarding this, visit [Difference between ng add  vs npm install  QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50169762/5720148)!

To install using Angular CLI, run this script:

`ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@latest`

> You can replace `@latest` version with a target version like `@12.0.1`, to install an older version, you can find the version history in their [github link here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)