# Difference between ng add <package name> vs npm install <package name> in angular 6

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angular6

As Angular6 has been released, 
They have added a new command [ng add](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/schematics/collection.json) . Can anyone tell me what will be the difference between existing `command npm install <package>` and `ng add <package>`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

### ng add

`ng add <package>` uses your package manager and installs the dependency. That dependency can have an installation script which can be used to do more job except the dependency installation. It can update your configurations, download another dependencies based on that one or create scaffold templates *(with initial markup and logic*).

To use `ng add` for a third party dependency, that team must provide *schematics* which describes the installation script. This can include some `.scss` or `.css` or related `.js` files to be included in the `angular.json` file.

In your provided link, you can install material package and also create some components with components

### npm install

`npm install <package>` just installs the dependency.

For more [**Version 6 of Angular Now Available**](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4).

Answer (score 36):

## [ng add](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4)

Will use your package manager to download new dependencies and invoke an installation script which can update your project with configuration changes (In `angular.json` file as well), add additional dependencies (e.g. polyfills if needed), or scaffold package-specific initialization code.

**For example** you run the command `ng add @angular/material — Install`, it will automatically install the package and configure in `angular.json` file too.

## npm install

Whereas `npm install <package>` will only install your package into your project but will not configure in order to use.

**For example** you run the command `npm install jquery` it will install jQuery in your project but you need to configure manually in `.angular-cli.json` file (as in v5)

For more information read out here -

- https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4

Comment: So, you mean a command like, `ng add <package >` will configure the package in `angular-cli.json` as well.

Comment: @Nimishgoel yes as per doc `ng add @angular/material — Install and setup Angular Material and theming and register new starter components into ng generate`

Comment: Thank you so much for nice examples. I got the ideas about what it does actually.

Answer (score 4):

As for Angular 7, take `@ngrx/store` package for example.

Besides installing packages and adding them to `package-lock.json` and `package.json`, `ng add` will do these for you.

1.Create file `index.ts` under `reducers` foler, and initialize root reducer.

```js
import {
   ActionReducer,
   ActionReducerMap,
   createFeatureSelector,
   createSelector,
   MetaReducer
} from '@ngrx/store';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

export interface State {

}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {

};

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<State>[] = !environment.production ? [] : [];
```

2.Add StoreModule to AppModule. (In file app.module.ts)

```js
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers, metaReducers } from './reducers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
  ]
})
```