# Where can I download a certain version of d3.js for angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js, chart.js, nvd3.js

I want to generate some graphs and I follow some tutorials but I think I am using a different version of d3.js because I keep getting weird errors like d3.line() is not a function or .interpolate is not a know method etc. Is there a way to download and use a earlier version of d3.js? Also any other good methods of generating charts (including a treemap) a large dataset that is updating every second? I have tried chart.js and n2-nvd3(not sure if this is the right name). Please be aware that I am new to typescript and angular in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are using d3-v3.

Try to install it by using:

```
npm i d3-3
```

Then you can import:

```
import * as d3 from 'd3-3';
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3

then go to versions. you can Use NPM to select the version you want.

Comment: Will this overwrite the d3.js version that I already have installed on my machine?

Comment: You can install multiple versions. you will just have to define which one you want to use.  here is a link showing that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-an-npm-package