# How to change material angular to old version?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

How to change material angular to last old version where we used `md` instead `mat`?

Now I have `"@angular/material": '^2.0.0-beta.8'`

Comment: get that version name in package.json and run `npm i` . Have i tried this ?

Comment: May be delete `^` and try reinstall npm?

Comment: Just specify the correct version in your `package.json` file **without the leading `^`**. Run `npm i` to install packages from the `package.json`.

Comment: `npm i ` gives me 3.5.2

Comment: In which section  `package.json` set version npm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a previous version of an npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-do-i-install-a-previous-version-of-an-npm-package)

Comment: Question is not about npm, question about material

Comment: npm i @angular/material@version

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade in the first place anyways?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62059033/how-can-i-update-downgrade-package-version-with-yarn/63021199#63021199). I had the same problem, and it is work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The latest version, where used `md` - `2.0.0-beta.11`.

Quote from [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deprecation-of-md-prefix):

> For beta.11, we've made the decision to deprecate the "md" prefix
>   completely and use "mat" moving forward. This affects all class names,
>   properties, inputs, outputs, and selectors (CSS classes were changed
>   back in February). The "md" prefixes will be removed in the next beta
>   release.

To change the version, use the following commands:

```
npm uninstall --save @angular/material
npm uninstall --save @angular/cdk
npm install --save-exact @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.11
npm install --save-exact @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.11
```