# How can I update/downgrade package version with yarn?

Tags: javascript, npm, yarnpkg

I have a package and I want to downgrade the version use. How can I do this with yarn "dependencies"?

Comment: Is it answer for your question https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade/

Comment: @Emre if your question is answered, please select the answer.

Answer (score 86):

| Yarn version | Command | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `yarn upgrade package@version` | `yarn upgrade luxon@^3.0.1` |
| 2, 3 | `yarn up package@version` | `yarn up luxon@^3.0.1` |

- Use `yarn -v` to check your Yarn version.
- Though the command is `upgrade`, it can be used for downgrading too.

Comment: Now for Yarn 2 the syntax is `yarn up package@version`.

Comment: For anyone getting zsh: no matches found, try adding quotes to the package:

yarn upgrade "luxon@^3.0.1"

Answer (score 29):

This is the official documentation https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/upgrade There is no keyword for downgrading to a specific version.you have to use the upgrade keyword for both

```
yarn upgrade package@version
```

For example

```
yarn upgrade @types/express-session@^1.15.16
```

Answer (score 18):

You can upgrade/downgrade a package interactively like so:

```
yarn upgrade my_package@^
```

This will produce an interactive list of available versions for the package for you to choose from. Like so:

```
Couldn't find any versions for "my_package" that matches "^"
? Please choose a version of "my_package" from this list: (Use arrow keys)
❯ 0.10.1
  0.10.0
  0.9.3
  0.9.2
  0.9.1
  0.9.0
  0.8.2
  0.8.0
```

One advantage of this method over using the `upgrade-interactive` keyword is that this produces an interactive list no matter what. While `upgrade-interactive` only gives you a list if your package is out of date. Thus, you can't always downgrade using the `upgrade-interactive` keyword.

Comment: This results in the message "More?" which is completely incomprehensible

Comment: There's no reason to cause an error to upgrade a package interactively. You can just use `yarn upgrade-interactive my_package`. You can also use the `--latest` parameter to bypass the version limit configured on `package.json`, if necessary.

Comment: @Cobra That doesn't work if you want to downgrade. `upgrade-interactive` will only work on packages that are out of date. 
As the documentation says: `yarn upgrade-interactive displays the outdated package list and lets you immediately chose which to upgrade`

My method will always give you an interactive list. Thus, also allowing you to downgrade packages.

Comment: @EmanuelLindström True. I honestly didn't even notice that the text of the question mentioned only downgrading, I was going by the title.