# npm install package.js - can I revert to earlier package?

Tags: npm, eslint

I am following [this tutorial on vue.js on YouTube](https://youtu.be/Fa4cRMaTDUI).  One of the packages I installed was eslint 5.5 (which is the current version).  I saw this error message:

```
npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 lint script 'eslint **/*.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the server package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     eslint **/*.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs server
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls server
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/jason/Documents/vue-movie/server/npm-debug.log
```

I tried updating Node and NPM, but that did not change this failure.  The tutorial is using "^4.6" and I was wondering if there is a way to revert the package I have to an earlier version?  And how would I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install a previous version of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/install-a-previous-version-of-a-package)