# installed angular version ~7.1.0 want to install version 4

Tags: angular, installation

I am trying to install **Angular 4**, but by default angular version ~7.1.0 is installing. I  do not require angular 7.

```
**package.json**
```

http://myjson.com/1dyoyq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install a previous version of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/install-a-previous-version-of-a-package)

Comment: can you post the content of your `package.json` (or at least the parts concerning angular)

If you want to install angular from scratch you'll have to include the version number in your npm install

`npm install @angular/[the package]@version`

Comment: support for angular 4 is ended. Better to go with the current version.

Comment: hi @Arikael, I want to install angular 4, so should be the command like this npm install -g @angular/cli@4.0.0

Comment: @Raman
Have a look at Lazars link.
your question really seems to be a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your package.json file to [https://api.myjson.com/bins/1eomlu](http://myjson.com/1eomlu) and then do an npm install.

In case you want to upgrade your angular version there is an online app that can help you [https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/](https://update.angular.io/). However this will not work for downgrading the version.