# How to upgrade NPM to specific version 6.4.1 on windows?

Tags: node.js, npm

On my windows 10 I have NPM 5.5.1 & Node 8.9.2 installed.

When I run the the command "npm i -g npm 6.4.1" I get bellow error. How to upgrade npm to 6.4.1 from 5.5.1 ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [install a previous version of a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/install-a-previous-version-of-a-package)

Comment: Use @ between module name and version: `npm@6.4.1` instead of `npm 6.4.1`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Better you try like this

> npm install -g npm@6.4.1