# Unable to install a particular version of a npm package

Tags: react-native, npm

I am trying to install `rn-fetch-blob@0.10.15`. but it's automatically installing the latest version i.e `0.10.16`. I tried to install as follows,

```
npm install rn-fetch-blob@0.10.15
```

as per this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/install-a-previous-version-of-a-package), it should work as expected. But not working in my case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can try `npm unlink <package>` before install a specific version of a package or remove `package-lock.json`/`yarn.lock`.

Answer (score 1):

Directly change your `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.10.15",
     ...
  }
```

And run: `npm install --save`

NOTE: With npm 5 and above you don't need the `--save` flag and `package-lock.json` file gets updated every time you do `npm install`

Comment: I had already tried it. Still, latest version is being installed. Any alternative?

Comment: I had tried to reproduce the same thing. I installed latest version via simple `npm install` which is `rn-fetch-blob@0.10.16` and then simply changed that package.json and did `npm install`. It worked. Another thing you can try is uninstall it cleanly then do `npm cache clean --force` and then repeat my steps.

Comment: After doing this how can i ensure that latest version has been installed? I mean what is the command to know currently installed version?

Comment: @Kishore To ensure latest installation either do it manually with `npm install <package-name>` or use a manager package like `ncu npm-check-updates`. To check what packages are installed `npm list --depth=0` OR even better `npm outdated` which'll give currently installed packages and if their updated versions exists.

Comment: `npm list --depth=0`is listing all the packages. is there any command to know about  particular package?

Comment: @Kishore `npm outdated` should give you a fair idea about all the packages installed with versions and update available. For specific package you could try `npm info <package-name> version` which will give what`s latest available about that but it doesn't show any info on currently installed. [More](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)