# How can i downgrade Bootstrap 4 to 3.3.7 for Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I am developing a laravel project.
I have the latest version of `bootstrap` (4.0.0) in my `package.json`.
How can I downgrade from bootstrap `4.0.0` to `3.3.7` for my laravel Project?

Comment: Depends: are you building the sources yourself? Are you using a cdn? Please provide more information.

Comment: Hey , this is my package json file: http://prntscr.com/qv2wdl | am build with npm install so installing latest version bootstrap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install a previous exact version of a NPM package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-to-install-a-previous-exact-version-of-a-npm-package)

Answer (score 1):

You can install Bootstrap using npm:

```
npm install bootstrap@3 --save
```

> For specific version - npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save

Comment: Thanks for answer but after this command updated for :"bootstrap": "^3.4.1" and still not work my style web pages..

Comment: You must recompile your css and js assets using : npm run dev

Comment: @Vedat Just be more specific with the version i.e. `npm install bootstrap@3.3.7` (the yellow bit in the answer).

Comment: @Rwd i got error : npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for bootstrap@3.3.7-npm.

Comment: @Vedat remove the `-npm` from the end. It should just be `npm install boostrap@3.3.7 --save` .

Comment: @Vedat As in it won't install bootstrap or something else isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to edit your **package.json** file

**Replace:**

```
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
```

**to**

`"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",`

and run `npm install`

That's all you need to do

Comment: Hey Faizan, im trying your solution but still not working. Am restarting everything for working but nothing else. What can i do

Comment: what's happening after doing these steps

Comment: after npm install run this command npm run dev to recompile your assets

Comment: Then i think one issue need to be fixed  Edit **app.scss** file which will found at **resources/assets/sass** make sure this file import **bootstrap 3.3.7** not **bootstrap 4**. Now **run npm run dev**. I hope this time all good to go

Comment: Something like **@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";** in place of **@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';** and then run **npm run dev**