# Different commands give different npm versions when check for installed npm version

Tags: react-native, npm

As per this [SO Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890958/how-to-install-a-previous-exact-version-of-a-npm-package) I tired to install the specific version of `react-native-calendars` like follows,

```
npm install react-native-calendars@1.212.0
```

Once the installation is done I am able to see it in package.json like this

```
"react-native-calendars": "^1.212.0"
```

This indicates required venison is installed.

When I ran `npm view react-native-calendars version` result is **1.1252.0** -- which is latest version of `react-native-calendars`.

when I ran `npm list react-native-calendars` result is `-- react-native-reanimated@1.13.2`

1. what is `npm` command to be used to check for installed `npm package` version?

Answer (score 0):

`npm view` shows the package on the remote NPM repository.

`npm list` shows the package version installed.

`package.json` shows the package version range to be used.

The `-- ...` in `npm list` is showing it's dependencies in a tree. To see *just* the package, use `npm list package --depth=0`.

Comment: So, both `npm view <Package name> version` and `npm view <package name> versions` gives both remote versions, right! Then what would be the difference between these two commands?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using `npm list`, which is the correct command to check node modules version. But the strange thing is that its returning a different version other than mentioned in package json. So I think you need to do 3 things.

```
1: Uninstall the package completely.
2: Clean gradlew cache and install the module again mentioning specific version number and check again.
3: Start npm with --reset-cache.
```