Why if I try to use the node.js module 'date-fns' I get the TypeScript compilation error TS1005?
I'm trying to use the format function of the Node.js module date-fns.
Some info about my system (obtained by the command ng --version) is reported below:
Angular CLI: 13.2.0
Node: 16.13.2
Package Manager: npm 8.6.0
OS: linux x64

I have installed date-fns by the command:
npm install date-fns

I have written an example file test_typescript.ts with the following code:
import { format } from 'date-fns';

const currentDate: Date = new Date();
const formattedDate: string = format(currentDate, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
console.log(formattedDate);

If I try to compile it by the following command:
tsc src/test_typescript.ts

I obtain the following error TS1005:
node_modules/date-fns/clamp.d.ts:18:59 - error TS1005: '?' expected.
18   Options extends ClampOptions<infer DateType extends Date>
                                                             ~

node_modules/date-fns/closestTo.d.ts:18:63 - error TS1005: '?' expected.
18   Options extends ClosestToOptions<infer DateType extends Date>
                                                                 ~

node_modules/date-fns/interval.d.ts:21:62 - error TS1005: '?' expected.
21   Options extends IntervalOptions<infer DateType extends Date>
                                                                ~
Found 3 errors.

The problem is in the import. How can I solve it?

Angular 13 and Node 16 are quite old - what version of TypeScript? You might have to upgrade your app or downgrade the library version.

@jonrsharpe if I execute tsc --version the version is 4.5.5

Looks like you need TS v5 to use date-fns v4, e.g. https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/3870

@jonrsharpe Can you help me to downgrade the version of date-fns? In this moment I can't upgrade the other software and  I prefer downgrade it. I'm not able to understand very wel what your github link suggests and I think is relative to an other error TS1383. I'm quite new on node.js, typescript and angular

https://stackoverflow.com/q/15890958/3001761

The TypeScript version is too old for the date-fns version
Thanks to @jonrsharpe (see the comments to the question) I have solved my problem which is a compatibility conflict between the version of the module date-fns and the version of the TypeScript compiler installed on my system.
In particular the TypeScript compiler version 4.5.5 doesn't support the version 4.1.0 of date-fns (this is the date-fns version released until today and this version has been installed by default by the command npm install date-fns).
This is highlighted by the jonrsharpe's comment:

Looks like you need TS v5 to use date-fns v4 ...

So I have removed the installed module by the command:
npm uninstall date-fns

Downgrade date-fns to version 2.30.0
After that I have followed some of the steps described in this post.
The first step is to get the list of date-fns versions available by the following command:
npm view date-fns versions

In the list there are many versions so by many downgrade attempts, which led me to other compilation errors, I have found that the newest version compliant with my TypeScript compiler (version 4.5.5) is the date-fns version 2.30.0.
So I have installed it by the command:
npm install date-fns@2.30.0

Compilation and execution of my script
After this downgrade I have been able to compile and execute my test file:
# compilation
tsc src/test_typescript.ts

# execution
node src/test_typescript.js

# output
23/10/2024 17:41


I had the same Issue and I tried playing around with typescript version until it worked for me
I have a vuetify 3 project and typescript version 4.5.5 updated to 4.7.4 and it worked

In my case I have executed a downgrade of the module date-fns from 4.1.0 to 2.30.0. You have chosen to upgrade the typescript version compiler from 4.5.5 to 4.7.4. The comment of @jonrsharpe (see above) suggests to upgrade the typescript compiler to the version 5.
